# jquery ajax return error object

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to do an ajax request to a php file when form is submitted, using jquery. I write this code:

```
$.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'send_password.php',
           data: 'mail_to='+ $('input[name$="email"]').val()+'&new_password='+new_password,
           success: function(response){
               alert(response);
           },
           error: function(r){
               alert(r);
               return false;
           }
       });
```

The problem is that this function return error, so i get an alert message, that contains "[Object object]" message and the form go to the action page and doesn't stop, like it doesn't see return false line (after alert(r)).
How can I do?
Thanks, Mattia

Comment: i get [Object object] also if I write object.toString()

Comment: I mean, what is the error that is returned. You should be able to see it in the console. Alerting `[Object object]` is not indicative of an error in your javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you wanna halt your script until the request is complete, u should use async:false. http://jsfiddle.net/Z8sRF/

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
data: 'mail_to='+ $('input[name$="email"]').val()+'&new_password='+new_password,
```

to

```
data: 'mail_to='+ $("#email").val()+'&new_password='+new_password,
```

and it should work

can you add the id to it ?

Comment: input has no id, but only name.

Comment: You missed the quotes around the selector - amended for you.